# Regular expression in C# for paths

Tags: c#, regex, url

I need help in getting a regular expresion for the following:

```
/_layouts/images/ABC.RadToolBarWebPart/add.png
```

And a url which could be complete or relative. Some examples:

```
~/Realtime/ABCSoft/Pages/My-Application.aspx
www.xyz.com
http://xyz.com
https://xyz.com
```

I have tried "/_layouts/images/" + "^[a-zA-z0-9./]*.[jpg|gif|png]$" for the image 
and "^[~]*[/a-zA-Z0-9]+.[aspx|com|net]$" for the URL

Thanks!

Comment: what part of the url are you interested in.   Just the last part,  e.g. add.png, aaaa.aspx?    You need to explain in more detail that you are trying to match as otherwise we can't answer the question

Comment: I'd also like to add: what have you tried?

Comment: Alistair: The entire paths mentioned. Brad: I have tried  "/_layouts/images/" + "^[a-zA-z0-9./]*.[jpg|gif|png]$" for  the image and "^[~]*[/a-zA-Z0-9]+.[aspx|com|net]$" for the URL.

Comment: @DotNetDude: `(.*)` should work flawlessly then.

Comment: Do you want to _test_ whether the path matches your regular expression? If so, what paths _do_ match, and what paths _don't_ match? Or do you want to extract one or more parts from each path? If so, which parts are you interested in?

Comment: Brad: Could you specify the changes to the Regex I have mentioned above'

Comment: Ok to be more precise in the first one: ABC.RadToolBarWebPart/add.png is the exact part I would be interested in. And in the latter part of my question, I'm interested in the entire path.

Answer (score 2):

Uri and its [Uri.Segments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments.aspx) will be better option than regular expressions. It will properly handle encodings which you would otherwise need to manually remove...

Answer (score 0):

well the following works for the supplied paths. Not exactly elegant though (add ^ and $ at your discretion).

```
((https?://)|(~/)|(/)|)(([a-zA-Z .\_-]+)+/?)+
```